# Authentication in Active Directory logs in without actually Logging in

Tags: c#, forms, web, authentication, ldap

I did an LDAP Login for my Project and it did worked with Login (Entering Password etc.) But now im having a Problem! It logs me automatic in (I deleted my Cookies already) Without even using my Code for the LDAP (It takes my domain Account as the username and grants me the right, that only users should have.) I looked in the Global ASAX and deleted the Code there. I did look in my web.config, here is the code:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" defaultUrl="Home.aspx" loginUrl="Login.aspx" name="adAuthCookie" path="/" protection="None" timeout="10">
  </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

So can you tell at which places i can look further, where is the Login from the forms (If i dont us the code above, the Login doesnt show, but still logs me in!)
Please help me, i have no Idea anymore.
Edit: I did looked my whole Code, theres no sign in, log, LDAP, or Forms, but its still takes me as a User!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you enabled Windows authentication on your Web site? Check in IIS manager:

1. Open the IIS Management Console on the web server
2. Expand the Sites folder
3. Click on the site concerned by your project
4. Double-Click the IIS - Authentication option
5. Under Authentication, check the state of Anonymous Authentication and Windows Authentication

Comment: Hello Thanks for that answer, i did do an other login mechanics but thanks for that help!